# synchronization of of ajax calls with function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to achieve something like below :

```
$.getJSON('api/filterTemplate/dashboard', function (data) {

        $.map(data, function (rec, i) {
          $.get('commonCore/templates/' + rec.templateHtml, function (html) {
               filterTemplate = Handlebars.compile(html);

                replaceFilterTemplate(data[i].classids);// this functions appends html to div -data[i].classids 
            });
        });
});
```

but due to asynchronous behavior of AJAX, html is not getting appended to its correct div id. Can somebody help me with this code and suggest me some way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean it's not appended to the right DIV, what element is the data appended to, and what is the issue ?

Comment: You have `rec` and `i` backwards in your `map` and you should probably be using `each`

Comment: does `replaceFilterTemplate` rely on `filterTemplate` being global? if so there's part of your problem. If not where does `filterTemplate` get used? SHow code for `replaceFilterTemplate`

Comment: @megawac - in $.map the parameters are opposite, the index is last, but agree with you on using $.each instead, there doesn't seem to be any mapping going on here.

Comment: really? jQuery loops are so silly

Comment: @adeneo when first html is appeneded inside it has another div id where next will be attached and so on. but due to async call 2 comes before first and so on.

Comment: @charlietfl yes. but dint get on what you are pointing. can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: I'm still not really sure I get it, in a for loop we often keep the value of i constant with closures, but with a jQuery loop that shouldn't be neccessary. I see how ajax request 2 can finish before 1 etc. but the value of i shouldn't change, so I don't get why that would be an issue ?

Comment: Why not just make your service at `api/filterTemplate/dashboard` return the templates?

Answer (score 2):

Using a promise should maintain order (see [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/))

```
$.getJSON('api/filterTemplate/dashboard', function (data) {
    var promises = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, rec) {
        promises.push($.get('commonCore/templates/' + rec.templateHtml));
    });
    $.when.apply(this, promises).then(function() { //after all requests complete
        $.each(arguments, function(i, html) {
            filterTemplate = Handlebars.compile(html);
            replaceFilterTemplate(data[i].classids);// this functions appends html to div -data[i].classids
        })
    })
});
```

Also I suggest you pass `filterTempaltes` to `replaceFilterTemplate` instead of having it global/scoped